# How to query by one field and order by another field in Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

Request has a student property and a SQL Date field called SentDate. I'm trying to get Requests based on one Student, and get them sorted by the SentDate field. I've tried many different queries but I just can't get it right. Read on stack that I need a 'By' between Student and OrderBy, but that didn't solve it either.

`List<Request> findAllByStudentByOrderBySentDate(Student student);`

I get the error:
***No property by found for type Student! Traversed path: Request.student.***

Request:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long request_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Student student;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "study_group_id")
private StudyGroup studyGroup;

private Date sentDate;

private Time time;

private String message;
...other fields
```

Student:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long student_id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Request> requests;
...other fields
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Student property`? Does it have a field called student? Show entity class

Comment: Its a field, a Student object

Comment: How are you getting the student you are passing in?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but Marco's answer worked! Appreciate you taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try ( i put DESC as the sort direction, you could also try ASC)

```
List<Request> findByStudentOrderBySentDateDesc(Student student);
```

Comment: Didn't get an error this time at least, but it returned 0 results when it should return 4 requests... thanks for the help though. EDIT: Nvm, it worked! Thanks mate, I had a stupid error somewhere else..